# React Axios call pending after several calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have created an axios client for reuseable config and my axios client pending my API after the first several calls.

Instance

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiUrl,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "",
  },
});
```

API call

```
function apiPostData(url,postData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axiosClient
      .post(url,postData)
      .then((res) => {
        resolve(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        reject(e);
      });
  });
}
```

It works just fine at the first 4-5 calls, response time takes ~200ms. But after that, my react app pending my API call and it took me around a minute to get response.

And I have no idea how this happened.

middle function

```
export function getDataList(code,filter) {
  return apiPostData(
    "/xxx/yyy/dataList",
    {"code": code,"filter":filter},
  );
}
```

call in view

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getDataList(code,filter)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        errorHandler();
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Given that its working 4-5 times and then its taking too much time, looks like a backend API issue, rather than a front end issue, thats call I can say with the limited information provided

Comment: I have checked api log, it did not recieve my call until the pending is over. And api response in a resonable time

Comment: If you are sure that it's not a backend issue, I think you have to share more code. where this function is called (whatever hook you used etc)

Comment: I have add some new code, please check

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you've fallen prey to the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/283366). Your code will be much cleaner if you don't do that